# implementation of ioctl in freebsd

Tags: c, device-driver, freebsd, ioctl

I want to know how to implement `ioctl` command for a character device in FreeBSD.
I already write a character device with `open()` `close()` `read()` `write()` but I don't know what argument should I pass to `ioctl_handler`. Does anybody know the prototype of `d_ioctl_t`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick google search found [this](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/ident?im=excerpts;i=d_ioctl_t) page where `d_ioctl_t` is defined as:

```
typedef int d_ioctl_t(struct cdev *dev, u_long cmd, caddr_t data, int fflag, struct thread *td);
```